# Can't display a component using ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have to "generate" a new component on button click, by default I want to show the last added product on page after load and after navigate throught the other products.

When I retrieved all the product, on the `complete` function I'll call the `createComponent()` method and provide the last id.

```
// global variables
@ViewChild('productDetails', {read: ViewContainerRef}) entry: ViewContainerRef;
componentRef: any;

// create child component method
createComponent(id: number) {
  if (this.entry) {
    this.entry.clear();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ProductDetailsComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
    this.componentRef.instance.id = this.id = id;
  }
}

// Get list and generate component
ngOnInit() {
  this.list$ = this.listService.getList().subscribe(
    (response: IProducts[]) => {
      response.map((item, index) => {
        if (!this.id) {
          this.id = +item.Id;
        }

        if (!item.IsExpired) {
          item.style = 'card-disabled';
        } else {
          item.style = this.colors[index];
        }

        this.list.push(item);
      });
    },
    reason => console.error(reason),
    () => this.createComponent(this.id)
  );
}
```

But at the first time the console tell me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined`. But  after other clicks on the other product the component is showing correctly.

Comment: have you tried to debug and check the state of  this.entry when the error happens?

Comment: @RonaldKorze Ok, I try to debug the angular project and it seem that when I try to create the component the `entry` variable still null, but I noticed if I use `setTimeout` to set the value after `X` seconds it works (?), (code: `setTimeout(() => this.createComponent(this.id), 0)` on complete function of subscribe), I think that it could probably be a async problem, but I don't know where.

Comment: @SimoneDalMas can you please provide stackblitz link

Comment: @RezaRahmati https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yj6fn6, I have create a similar code with the same problem

Comment: @SimoneDalMas what is the issue the, I don't see any console.error. (see the picture in my answer) , I only changed this line to make it compile since it's ng8 (` @ViewChild('productDetails', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) entry: ViewContainerRef;`)

Comment: @RezaRahmati Ok, i saw, on stackblitz the entry doesn't give a null value (i don't know why is different on my machine...) but, the problem is similar: it doen't show the product "on page load". I mean, I put the method call on `complete` function of the subscription and it should display the item, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

do you have an instance of productDetails in your main component?

you need to add the productDetails in your template/ html
in html template add div element:

```
<div #productDetails></div>
```

Comment: I know, the view works fine, but the problem is the `entry` variable which is still `null` on the first call of the method `createComponent()`

Comment: try for testing to call the function on button click

Comment: I already do it and it works, the view will show if I click on button, but the problem is located in a different part

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply on my comment: try to move that code from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit, I think then the ViewContainerRef should be ready

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, the `entry` still null

Answer (score 0):

viewChild is available on `AfterViewInit` for example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
  .....

  @ViewChild('productDetails', {read: ViewContainerRef}) entry: ViewContainerRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Values on ngAfterViewInit():');
    console.log("entry:", this.entry);
  }  

  .....
}
```

temporary image will be removed

[image: temporary will be removed]

Comment: thought the same, but according to Simone this didn't help

Comment: @RonaldKorze I asked him to provide stackblitz, it might be something else not working